# Confused with gradle select rule of dependency version

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

I have import dependency `implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-jetty", version: "2.1.18.RELEASE"` in project A. And here is dependency tree:

[image]

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty -> 2.1.18.RELEASE
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |              \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.4.33.v20201020 -> 9.4.48.v20220622
|    |                   +--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0 -> 4.0.1
|    |                   +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.48.v20220622 -> 9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |                   \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.48.v20220622 -> 9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    \--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0 -> 4.0.1
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
|    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
|    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:9.0
|    |    |         +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
|    |    |         +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:9.0
|    |    |         |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
|    |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:9.0
|    |    |              \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:9.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:9.4.33.v20201020
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:9.4.33.v20201020 (*)
|    |    \--- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.0 -> 1.1
|    \--- org.mortbay.jasper:apache-el:8.5.54
```

I can not understand why module `jetty-server` upgrade from `9.4.33.v20201020` to `9.4.48.v20220622`，because other jetty module version remain at `9.4.33.v20201020`

And I import dependency `implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-jetty", version: "2.1.18.RELEASE"` in another clean project B. And here is dependency tree:

[image]

All jetty module version is unified：9.4.45

Why does the same dependency `implementation group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-jetty", version: "2.1.18.RELEASE` refer different version of module jetty

Answer (score 0):

As you may know Gradle `implementation` acts transitively which means any dependencies bring its dependencies. Although your `jetty-server` version is `9.4.33.v20201020` but somehow `spring-boot-starter-jetty` is dependent on `jetty-servlets:9.4.48.v20220622` so it's being brought. However, it's a little waired that your second screenshot shows version `9.4.45` because I myself test it with an isolated project and the version was `9.4.48`. Anyway, you can inform the `implementation` to not act completely transitively and exclude some dependencies like blow:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:2.1.18.RELEASE")
        {
            exclude group: "org.eclipse.jetty"
        }
```

But if there is `org.eclipse.jetty` that `spring-boot-starter-jetty` is dependent on, you had to put it inside your `build.gradle` or exclude the malicious module specifically like blow:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:2.1.18.RELEASE")
        {
            exclude group: "org.eclipse.jetty",  module: "jetty-servlets"
        }
```

Comment: I know this solution. I am just confused about the version change between different project, and I do not understand how sprint-boot-starter manage dependencies version